Custom Metric with Keras without Eagerly execution
I have read the few questions on this topic which were discussed in how to implement custom metric in keras? and How to calculate F1 Macro in Keras?.
The information on those pages and the Keras documentation was enough to help me implement the Cohen-Kappa_Score as a metric for my application, however there are a few draw backs in this implementation that I cannot overcome:


The code only works if I set tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
This code runs on CPU only while the model runs on GPU, significantly slowing down the execution.
It also does not work if I set os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "jax"


I also implemented the other option that was suggested in the previous post, by implementing a callback and calculating the cohen_kappa_score at the end of each epoch, but that required passing in the validation data and the screen was filled with thousands of rows showing 1/1 =================== 0s. Even setting verbose=0 would not eliminate that nasty output. It also required calculating the metric with all the validation data after each epoch!! Effectively making that approach unworkable.
I am hoping someone can help me implement a version of my QwkMetric that can run with normal settings.
As an FYI, I have located a version that is made for use by models designed for Ordinal Regression applications that works extremely well. I am trying to write this version for Non-Ordinal Multi-class classification.
I am using:
 tf version:  2.15.0
 kears version:  2.15.0
 numpy version:  1.25.2

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, Callback
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score

import keras
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K


class QwkMetric(Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='qwk', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.y_true = self.add_weight(name='y_true', shape=(0,), dtype=tf.int32)
        self.y_pred = self.add_weight(name='y_pred', shape=(0,), dtype=tf.int32)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
      # Flatten and cast y_true and y_pred to integer values
      y_true = K.cast(K.reshape(y_true, [-1]), 'int32')
      y_pred = K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), 'int32')

      # Concatenate the current batch's y_true and y_pred with the state variables
      if(len(self.y_true) > 0):
        self.y_true = tf.concat([self.y_true, y_true], axis=0)
      else :
        self.y_true = y_true

      if(len(self.y_pred) > 0):
        self.y_pred = tf.concat([self.y_pred, y_pred], axis=0)
      else:
        self.y_pred = y_pred

    def result(self):

      # Compute QWK using sklearn's cohen_kappa_score
      y_true_np = K.get_value(self.y_true)
      y_pred_np = K.get_value(self.y_pred)
      qwk_score = cohen_kappa_score(y_true_np, y_pred_np, weights='quadratic')
      return qwk_score

    def reset_state(self):
      # Clear the state
      self.y_true = tf.zeros([0], dtype=tf.int32)
      self.y_pred = tf.zeros([0], dtype=tf.int32)

qwk_metric = QwkMetric()

# Generate some synthetic data
num_samples = 1000
num_features = 20
num_classes = 5

X_train = np.random.random((num_samples, num_features)).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, num_samples).astype(np.int32)

X_val = np.random.random((num_samples, num_features)).astype(np.float32)
y_val = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, num_samples).astype(np.int32)

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).cache().batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val)).cache().batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


# Create a simple model for testing
def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(20,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=[qwk_metric])
    return model

model = create_model()

# Define the ModelCheckpoint callback
checkpoint_cb = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5',
                                monitor='val_qwk',
                                mode='max',
                                save_best_only=True,
                                verbose=1)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb],
    verbose=1
)

# Print the QWK metric values
print("Final QWK on training data:", history.history['qwk'][-1])
print("Final QWK on validation data:", history.history['val_qwk'][-1])

implemented two versions of custom metric, both have shortcomings that make it difficult to use. I have read and implemented prior suggestions on this topic.

I was able to modify the code that was written for Ordinal Regression and convert it for normal classification models. This version now works as any other metric. It can be used in model.compile() and in callbacks. It is registered as qwk, therefore callbacks will use monitor='val_qwk'.
If you see an error AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute "ops"
upgrade keras with !pip install --upgrade keras and all should be good
The code below comes with a quick test that compares the results of this calculation with the sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score to make sure they match.
There are two things to note:

This code will not run with os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "jax" . Use "tensorflow" instead.
This custom class is about 5 times slower than the sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score.

Perhaps one of you can fix the issue with jax backend and speed it up further.
#!pip install --upgrade keras

import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow" 


import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, Callback
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score

import keras

print(" tf version: ", tf.__version__)
print(" kears version: ", keras.__version__)
print(" numpy version: ", np.__version__)

tf version:  2.15.0 
kears version:  3.3.3 
numpy version:  1.25.2 
keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy("mixed_float16")

class QwkMetric(Metric):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, epsilon=1e-6, name="qwk", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.epsilon = epsilon

        label_vec = keras.ops.arange(num_classes, dtype=keras.backend.floatx())
        self.row_label_vec = keras.ops.reshape(label_vec, [1, num_classes])
        self.col_label_vec = keras.ops.reshape(self.row_label_vec, [num_classes, 1])
        col_mat = keras.ops.tile(self.col_label_vec, [1, num_classes])
        row_mat = keras.ops.tile(self.row_label_vec, [num_classes, 1])
        self.weight_mat = (col_mat - row_mat) ** 2

        self.numerator = self.add_weight(name="numerator", initializer="zeros")
        self.denominator = self.add_weight(name="denominator", initializer="zeros")
        self.o_sum = self.add_weight(name="o_sum", initializer="zeros")
        self.e_sum = self.add_weight(name="e_sum", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = keras.ops.cast(y_true, dtype=self.col_label_vec.dtype)
        y_pred = keras.ops.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), dtype=self.weight_mat.dtype)
        batch_size = keras.ops.shape(y_true)[0]

        # removing tf.32 from (tf.cast(y_true, tf.int32), self.num_classes)
        y_true = keras.ops.one_hot(keras.ops.cast(y_true, tf.uint8), self.num_classes)
        y_pred = keras.ops.one_hot(keras.ops.cast(y_pred, tf.uint8), self.num_classes)

        # Compute weight for numerator
        cat_labels = keras.ops.matmul(y_true, self.col_label_vec)
        cat_label_mat = keras.ops.tile(cat_labels, [1, self.num_classes])
        row_label_mat = keras.ops.tile(self.row_label_vec, [batch_size, 1])

        weight = (cat_label_mat - row_label_mat) ** 2

        self.numerator.assign_add(keras.ops.sum(weight * y_pred))

        # Compute weights for denominator
        label_dist = keras.ops.sum(y_true, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        pred_dist = keras.ops.sum(y_pred, axis=0, keepdims=True)

        w_pred_dist = keras.ops.matmul(
            self.weight_mat, keras.ops.transpose(pred_dist, [1, 0])
        )
        self.denominator.assign_add(
            keras.ops.sum(keras.ops.matmul(label_dist, w_pred_dist))
        )

        self.o_sum.assign_add(keras.ops.sum(y_pred))
        self.e_sum.assign_add(keras.ops.sum(
            keras.ops.matmul(keras.ops.transpose(label_dist, [1, 0]), pred_dist)
        ))

    def result(self):
        return 1.0 - (
            keras.ops.divide_no_nan(self.numerator, self.denominator)
            * keras.ops.divide_no_nan(self.e_sum, self.o_sum)
        )

    def reset_state(self):
        self.numerator.assign(0)
        self.denominator.assign(0)
        self.o_sum.assign(0)
        self.e_sum.assign(0)
        

# Define a short set of data
y_true = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0])
y_pred_prob = np.array([
    [0.9, 0.05, 0.05],  # close to 0
    [0.05, 0.85, 0.10], # close to 1
    [0.10, 0.10, 0.80], # close to 2
    [0.05, 0.20, 0.75], # close to 2
    [0.60, 0.30, 0.10], # closer to 0 but true is 1
    [0.40, 0.50, 0.10], # closer to 1 but true is 0
])


y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred_prob, axis=1)

%%timeit -n1 -r1
# Using scikit-learn
kappa_score_sklearn = cohen_kappa_score(y_true, y_pred, weights='quadratic')
print(f"Sklearn Cohen's Kappa: {kappa_score_sklearn:.4f}")

Sklearn Cohen's Kappa: 0.7500 
2.36 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each) 
# Create and update custom metric
qwk_metric = QwkMetric(num_classes=3)

%%timeit -n1 -r1
qwk_metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred_prob)
kappa_score_custom = qwk_metric.result().numpy()

print(f"Custom Keras Metric Cohen's Kappa: {kappa_score_custom:.4f}")

Custom Keras Metric Cohen's Kappa: 0.7500 
11.7 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each) 
